# R repeat individual numbers within numeric sets in nested list

Tags: r, list, vector

I have a set of alpha-numeric vectors:

```
lst <- list(c("三垣3-19", "6", "81497", "79992", "79101", 
"77760", "75973", "75411", "74666"), c("蒼龍1-01", "2", "66249", "65474", "66803", "64238"), c("蒼龍1-02", "1", "64238"), "蒼龍1-03")

[[1]]
[1] "三垣3-19" "6"        "81497"    "79992"   
[5] "79101"    "77760"    "75973"    "75411"   
[9] "74666"   

[[2]]
[1] "蒼龍1-01" "2"        "66249"    "65474"   
[5] "66803"    "64238"   

[[3]]
[1] "蒼龍1-02" "1"        "64238"   

[[4]]
[1] "蒼龍1-03"
```

The second number on each vector (i.e. 6,2,1) represents the total number of lines to be drawn to connect stars, given by their HIP number to the right, together. Each pair of HIP number indicates a line drawn between 2 stars.

Hence `81497 79992` in `[[1]]` would mean "draw a line between star number "81497" and "79992", so on and so forth.

In the case of a continuous line, such as `[[1]]`, the numbers between "81497" and "74666" should be repeated so that there is no break in the lines.

Thus, in the case of `[[1]]`, `"79992" "79101" "77760" "75973" "75411"` should be repeated to give the following result:

```
[[1]]
 [1] "三垣3-19" "6"        "81497"    "79992"   
 [5] "79992"    "79101"    "79101"    "77760"   
 [9] "77760"    "75973"    "75973"    "75411"   
[13] "75411"    "74666"   

[[2]]
[1] "蒼龍1-01" "2"        "66249"    "65474"   
[5] "66803"    "64238"   

[[3]]
[1] "蒼龍1-02" "1"        "64238"    "64238"   

[[4]]
[1] "蒼龍1-03"
```

Since the second element on each list represents the total number of lines to be drawn, a validity test can be coded to indicate whether certain numbers need to be repeated. Thus `6` in `[[1]]` means there should be 6 pairs (i.e. 6 * 2 = 12 elements) of HIP numbers that follow. When the validity test fails, I would like R to repeat the numbers in between the third and final elements for me so that the continuous line can be drawn.

---

The partial solution I managed to cobble up is as follows:

```
lapply(lst, function(x) x[2]) == (lengths(lst)-2)/2
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE    NA
```

This tests the HIP values for its validity. Only `[[2]]` fits into the description in the original list. `[[1]]` and `[[3]]` would be the vectors we need to work on.

To repeat individual values in-between a certain vector, I could do this:

```
> x <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
> x[2:4] <- lapply(x[2:4], function(x) rep(x, 2))
> unlist(x)
[1] 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5
```

However, because `lst` is a list, I cannot do:

```
lst[2:4] <- lapply(lst[2:4], function(x) rep(x, 2))
```

to get the same results. The fact that the end number (4, in this case) needs to be specified by `lengths(lst)` further complicates the matter.

I suppose the final code would be an `ifelse()` function to join the two functions described above.

---

**Clarification of the rule:**

The second element of each vector represents the desired number of distinct HIP pairs to draw a line.

`[[2]]` is valid because there are 2 pairs of numbers that follow, which fits the value given in its second element, so the numbers need not be repeated.

In this case, the lines most probably form a cross, rather than a continuous line. So the rule should be applied only in the case of a continuous line, such as `[[1]]`.

As for the case of [[3]], because there is only one point, the number is repeated as a rule, so that the validity given by the second element is sustained.

---

**BUG INQUIRY**

@TUSHAr: Your code seems to generate `NA` values when elements within the vectors contain non-numeric values.

```
lst <- list(c("三垣3-19", "6", "81497", "79992A", "79101", 
              "77760", "75973A", "75411", "74666"), c("蒼龍1-01", "2", "66249", "65474", "66803B", "64238"), c("蒼龍1-02", "1", "64238"), "蒼龍1-03")
```

Run the code with the above data and you get:

```
[[1]]
 [1] "三垣3-19" "6"        "81497"    NA         NA        
 [6] "79101"    "79101"    "77760"    "77760"    NA        
[11] NA         "75411"    "75411"    "74666"   

[[2]]
[1] "蒼龍1-01" "2"        "66249"    "65474"    NA        
[6] "64238"   

[[3]]
[1] "蒼龍1-02" "1"        "64238"    "64238"   

[[4]]
[1] "蒼龍1-03"
```

What is causing this, and is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Please check your second list items for 2, something is not correct

Comment: Each pair of HIP number indicates a line drawn between 2 stars. The numbers don't necessarily have to repeat themselves, if it is not a continuous line.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question, surely someone else will answer

Comment: The question is not really clear, however `tapply` and `rapply` might be what you are looking for

Comment: If you are replicating by the second element i.e. for the first list element it is 6.  So, are you sure the expected output is correct.  Based on the logic, `lapply(lst, function(x) if(length(x)>2) c(x[1:2], rep(x[3:length(x)], as.numeric(x[2]))) else x)`

Comment: @akrun, is the question clearer now?

Comment: sorry the rules are not clear to me.  For example, in the second case, with 2, the values are not replicated.  It seems to be the same as the one in the initial example and similarly for the next one.  So, are you saying that the pair only changes when the second value is greater?

Comment: No. `[[2]]` is valid because there are 2 pairs of numbers that follow, which fits the value given in its second element, so the numbers need not be repeated. For the case of `[[2]]` the lines most probably form a cross, rather than a continuous line. So the rule should be applied only in the case of a continuous line, like `[[1]]`.

Comment: @akrun: This is what I got so far from this question. the second element of each vector represents **n** the desired number of distinct pairs to draw a line. If the points in the vector are in a sequence, then the inner points are to be replicated such that **n** pairs can be achieved. There are lot of what-ifs which have not been made clear.

Comment: In the case of `[[3]]`, because there is only one point, the number is repeated as a rule so that the validity of the second element is sustained.

Comment: @Sati: I have a scenario for you: what if in case of [[2]] the required no of pairs was 5, is that possible? can we count out that possibility?

Comment: @TUSHAr: It cannot be 5, unless more HIP numbers are given manually.

Comment: @RicardoSaporta, could you take another look at the question? I have clarified certain points.

Comment: @Sati Please check if my answer works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing the first value of each `vector` in `lst` in a separate variable `id` to avoid unnecessary subsetting during processing.

```
id = lapply(lst,function(t){t[1]})
```

Removed the first element which is already stored in `id`.

```
lst = lapply(lst,function(t){
    t=t[-1]
    #if(length(t)>0){
    #    as.integer(t)
    #}
})
```

Loop through the processed `lst` object:

```
temp = lapply(lst,function(t){
#Use the first value as the desired number of pairs in `reqdpairs`
    reqdpairs = as.numeric(t[1])
#remove the first values so that `t` only contains HIP numbers.
    t=t[-1]
#calculate existing number of pairs for case [[2]] such that if all conditions are satisfied we don't do any processing 
    noofpairs = floor(length(t)/2)
#check if `t` contains values after removing the first element. The `else` part covers the case [[3]]
    if(length(t)>1){
#If `noofpairs` is not equal to `reqdpairs` use `rep` on the inner elements (**excluding the first and last element**) of the vector.
        if(noofpairs!=reqdpairs){
            pairs=c(reqdpairs,t[1],rep(t[-c(1,length(t))],each=2),t[length(t)])
        }else{
#In this case no processing is required so we just merge the reqdpairs with `t` as it is
            pairs=c(reqdpairs,t)
        }
    }else if(length(t)==1){
        pairs=rep(t[1],times=2) 
        pairs=c(reqdpairs,pairs)
    }else{
        pairs=NULL
    }
    pairs=as.character(pairs)
}
)
```

This step is to merge `id` with `temp` to achieve the desired output format. Basically just a concatenation step.

```
mapply(function(x,y){c(x,y)},id,temp)


#[[1]]
#[1] "三垣3-19" "6"        "81497"    "79992"    "79992"    "79101"    "79101"    "77760"    "77760"    "75973"   
#[11] "75973"    "75411"    "75411"    "74666"   

#[[2]]
#[1] "蒼龍1-01" "2"        "66249"    "65474"    "66803"    "64238"   

#[[3]]
#[1] "蒼龍1-02" "1"        "64238"    "64238"   

#[[4]]
#[1] "蒼龍1-03"
```

Comment: @Sati Added explanation and removed a few redundant steps.

Comment: The edited code seems to leave out the value before the HIP numbers after processing. `[[1]]
 [1] "三垣3-19" "81497"    "79992"    "79992"   
 [5] "79101"    "79101"    "77760"    "77760"   
 [9] "75973"    "75973"    "75411"    "75411"   
[13] "74666"` How do we put that back in?

Comment: @Sati The StackOverflow guidelines frown upon editing the code of another user's answer. Most likely your edit will be (actually now has been) rejected. Instead you should post a comment and let the poster edit the answer (like my next  comment, for example). I *could* have forced the edit through, but decided that that would be an abuse of my editing privilege.

Comment: @TUSHAr The line reading `pairs=c(t[1],rep(t[-c(1,length(t))],each=2),t[length(t)])` needs to be changed to `pairs=c(reqdpairs,t[1],rep(t[-c(1,length(t))],each=2),t[length(t)])` to fix the bug indicated by Sati's previous comment.

Comment: @robinCTS Thanks for reporting. I have edited my answer.

Comment: @Sati Thanks for reporting the issue. Fixed the answer now.

Comment: @TUSHAr: I think it is this part of the code that is causing the bug. `if(length(t)>0){as.integer(t)}` Is it absolutely necessary to convert all the  characters into numeric values?

Comment: @Sati what error are you getting now? I think you can skip that part and try once. Earlier I was writing a logic based on a the series of number so used that code. Let me know if it works after skipping the problematic code.

Comment: @TUSHAr: This is what I get after commenting out that function. 
`[[1]]
 [1] "三垣3-19" "三垣3-19" "6"        "81497"    "81497"   
 [6] "79992A"   "79992A"   "79101"    "79101"    "77760"   
[11] "77760"    "75973A"   "75973A"   "75411"    "75411"   
[16] "74666"   

[[2]]
 [1] "蒼龍1-01" "蒼龍1-01" "2"        "66249"    "66249"   
 [6] "65474"    "65474"    "66803B"   "66803B"   "64238"   

[[3]]
[1] "蒼龍1-02" "蒼龍1-02" "1"        "64238"   

[[4]]
[1] "蒼龍1-03" "蒼龍1-03" NA         NA`

Comment: `> # lst = lapply(lst,function(t){
> #   t=t[-1]
> #   if(length(t)>0){
> #     as.integer(t)
> #   }
> # })`

Comment: @Sati I have made changes in the code. Let me know if this works.

Comment: @TUSHAr: It works fine now, thanks! Could you explain how you fixed the bug?